# JSRender in HTML head

Tags: html, jsrender

Is there a way to create a JSRender template in the head of a HTML page? I want the meta tag for page title and description to pull in a variable from a JSON file. Example:

```
<meta name="description" content="{{:assets.meta_description}}">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to render and append the meta tag *after* loading a minimal html document.

Assuming *template* contains this markup:

```
<meta name="description" content="{{:assets.meta_description}}">
```

This code will add your meta tag to the head element.

```
var data = { assets: { meta_description: "My awesome page."} }
var $rendered = $(template.render(data));
$('html head').append($rendered);
```